# Making Range Function Act Over Given Values in Python

Tags: python, function, range

I would like to know if there is a way to make the range function act only over some given values.

I'm trying to write some code for Problem 2 of Project Euler where I must find the sum of the even-valued terms of the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed 4,000,000.

My code at the moment looks like this:

```
#Fibonacci Even Sum

even_sum = 0 

def fib(n):

    a, b = 1,2
    while a < n:
        print (a)
        a, b = b, a + b
    print ()
    return a

for i in range(fib(4000000)):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        even_sum = i + even_sum

print (even_sum)
```

The problem seems to be that my code adds up  *all* the even numbers up to 3524578, not just the even Fibonacci numbers. How can I change this?

Many thanks !

Comment: Rather than trying to make `range` do something it is absolutely not supposed to do, you should consider a different approach.

Comment: You are not creating a range of fibonacci numbers. You are creating a range up to the 4-millionth fibonacci number, singular. That range is still running from 0 to that number. Instead, find a way to share all those `a` values with the caller.

Comment: `fib(n)` returns a single number (the `n`th Fibonacci number - not the Fibonacci number closest to `n`!) - if you change `fib()` to build a list instead, you can iterate over that directly, and not use `range()` at all.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a generator function, `range()` does not suit your problem. You can convert your `fib` function to a generator by giving `yield a` inside the while loop, that would make the function keep spitting out fibonacci numbers till `n` and you can find sum like that.

Example of generator -

```
>>> def fib(n):
...     a, b = 1,2
...     while a < n:
...             yield a
...             a, b = b, a+b
...
>>>
>>>
>>>
>>> for i in fib(200):
...     print(i)
...
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
55
89
144
```

you can make similar changes to your function.

Code would look like -

```
even_sum = 0 

def fib(n):

    a, b = 1,2
    while a < n:
        print (a)
        a, b = b, a + b
        yield a

for i in fib(4000000):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        even_sum = i + even_sum

print (even_sum)
```